# missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to learn Python and have been searching through other questions which may relate to mine in order to understand what I am doing wrong to get such error.
I am trying to find palindromes using the following code:

```
def find_all_palindromes(string):
    string = string.lower()
    palindromes = []
    words = open("dictionary.txt")
    for word in words:
        word = word.strip()
        if string == word.lower()[::1]:
            palindromes.append(word)
    words.close
    return palindromes
```

with the following error appearing whenever I try run the code: `missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'`.

I would greatly appreciate if someone would direct me to where I am going wrong.

Edit: I should probably mention that my dictionary file includes one word per line so there is no need to take write a code that takes into account spaces as there will never be a sentence. There is also no capitalization in the words.

Comment: Did you pass an argument when calling the function `find_all_palindromes`?

Comment: Get rid of the `string` variable entirely.  A palindrome is a `word` such that `word == word[::-1]`.

Comment: @Filippidis no i did not

Comment: @PatrickHaugh even after removing `string = string.lower()` I still get the same error..

Comment: @pete change `def find_all_palindromes(string)` to `def find_all_palindromes()`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh this causes the following error to occur `local variable 'string' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 0):

With a file `dictionary.txt` that contains:

```
Able was I ere I saw Elba
Never odd or even
```

calling `find_all_palindromes('Never odd or even')` returns:

```py
['Never odd or even']
```

These palindromes are from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome). Taking the spaces into account, these are not palindromes. Also, the function `find_all_palindromes` just matches lines from the file `dictionary.txt` with the given string, and returns a `list` containing multiple occurrences of the string (preserving capitalization though, which may differ).

Another example is:

```
not a palindrome
Not a Palindrome
not A palindromE
```

With this file:

```py
>>> find_all_palindromes('not a palindrome')
['not a palindrome', 'Not a Palindrome', 'not A palindromE']
```

Comment: Did you really run this? OP's code does not account for spaces in between words.

Comment: I had run it, but the OP's function doesn't find palindromes, it only matches lines. I have added a counterexample to my answer. The question seems to be about the missing argument, so I use the given code (instead of writing different code to actually find palindromes).